# How to minimize the memory used by array

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, optimization, struct

I am trying to optimize the memory usage in a game. A lot of memory is taken up by a huge array of this struct:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a keyframe in an animation track.
/// </summary>
public struct BoneKeyframe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creats a new BoneKeyframe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="transform">The transform for the keyframe.</param>
    /// <param name="time">The time in ticks for the keyframe.</param>
    public BoneKeyframe(Matrix transform, long time)
    {
        this.Transform = transform;
        this.Time = time;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The transform for the keyframe.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly Matrix Transform;
    /// <summary>
    /// The time for the keyframe.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly long Time;

}
```

I want to replace the Transform member with a custom class/struct. 
It should contain an optional translation Vector3, optional scale Vector3 and a rotation quaternion (Vector4). 
How can I design it so it becomes as compact as possible...  the point is to reduce the total size of the BoneKeyFrame array.

Comment: Matrix is in the XNA namespace, it is a 4-by-4 float structure